# do rank order/decile in mysql with partition

Tags: mysql

I have multiple groups of cities in my dataset and I am trying to rank order price for each of those groups in mysql. Can someone help me convert the partition clause to mysql?

Comment: Please post your table structure and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presuming that you are looking for the equivalent of `rank() over (partition by city order by price)`.  You can do this with a subquery:

```
select d.*,
       (select 1 + count(price)
        from dataset d2
        where d2.city = d.city and d2.price < d.price
       ) as rank
from dataset d;
```

Or using variables:

```
select d.*,
       (@rn := if(@city = city and @price > price, if(@price = @price, @rn + 1, @rn + 1),
                  if(@city = city and @price = price, @rn,
                     if(@city := city, if(@price := price, 1, 1), 1)
                    )
                 )
       ) as rank                  
from dataset d cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @city := '', @price = -1)
order by city, price;
```

Comment: Shame I can't do +2 for the variables-based solution!

Comment: Table structure:



city     Price area_sqft Pricesqft
A     4620000     1100 4200
B     25000000     1800 13888
C           1000000         750         1333

I am trying to get something like 

City     Price       Rank or Decile
A         X1           1
A         X2           5

So i tried rank and NTILES but partition wasn't working. SO now I am trying NTILES in HIVE but I keep getting the following error: 
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NullPointerException null